# Vue JS add bulma class is-loading when button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bulma

I am trying out bulma. What I want is to [show the loading icon over a button](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/button/) when it is clicked.

Here it's the head part:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Button loading in Bulma</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>
```

This is the body code:

```
<div class="container">
        <!--Vue container-->
    <div id="app">
        <div class="tile notification is-info">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Newsletter</h1>
                <form>
                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input class="input is-small" type="email" id="email" placeholder="you@somewhere.com" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit button -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="control">
                            <button class="button is-primary" @click="loadingClass = 'is-loading'" :class="{ loadingClass }">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the vue.js script

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            loadingClass: ''
        }
    })
</script>
```

I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

**Solution:**

Well, I have found a workaround [here in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), so I have fixed it as follows:

Form:

```
<!-- Submit button -->
                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <button class="button is-primary" v-bind:class="{ 'is-loading' : loading }">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            loading: false
        }
    })
</script>
```

As I change in the console `app.loading=true;` the button does change to "loading" and viceversa with `app.loading=false;`
That's it.

Comment: that doesn't look like a workaround. That's how you're meant to do it. Except that you shouldn't double the class attribute. Try putting the static classes in with the dynamic, as I do below !

Answer (score 2):

Ok in your `data:` you want a pure description of the state of your page, so put `clicked : false`

Then in your handler, modify your state: `@click="clicked = true"`

Then in your dynamic class list, put the bulma loading class.

```
:class="{'button':true, 'is-primary':true, 'is-active':clicked}"
```

Does that cover it?